# Python:Find all words ending in text (re.findall)

Tags: python, regex

Load macOS.txt into a variable text.  Then do the following:
Find all the occurrences of **macOS, Mac OS, and OS X** in the text. Put the results in one list.
Print the list of those words then print the following:
There are {length of list} words mentioning macOS, Mac OS, or OS X in the text.

I think I should use REGULAR EXPRESSION.Like re.findall or re.finditer. **Anyone can correct my codes below?**

```
text = open("macOS.txt", "r")  
import re
pattern = '[A-Za-z0-9-]+' 
lines = "OS"  
ls = re.findall(pattern,lines)
print(ls)
```

*But how to Find all the occurrences of macOS, Mac OS, and OS X in the text?*

or this?

```
import re
with open('macOS.txt', 'r') as f:
  content = f.read()
temp = re.findall(\b(?!\w*OS\b)\w*OS\b)
print(f'There are {len(temp)} words ended with OS (other than OS and macOS) in the text.')
```

Comment: You can use an alternation to find all 3 exact matches `\b(?:macOS|Mac OS|OS X)\b`

Comment: This pattern `\b(?!\w*OS\b)\w*OS\b` will never match, as it first asserts that there should not be word characters followed by `OS` and then it tries to match what it just has asserted to not be there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use fuzzywuzzy library.
Take few letters before and after finding 'OS", use the fuzzywuzzy library to compare.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fuzzywuzzy-python-library/

Alternatively, if your output is limited to one word before and after 'OS', then you can just do this-

1. if that word contains OS (macOS)
2. find one word prior to OS => see if its 'Mac' => concat them
3. find one word after OS => see if its 'X' => concat them

Comment: import re
with open('macOS.txt', 'r') as f:
  content = f.read()
temp = re.findall(\b(?!\w*OS\b)\w*OS\b)
print(f'There are {len(temp)} words ended with OS (other than OS and macOS) in the text.')

Comment: import re
with open(‘macOS.txt’, ‘r’) as f:
  content = f.read()
 
pattern = r’macOS’
pattern1=r’OS’
# Replace all occurrences of character s with an empty string
temp = re.sub(pattern , ‘’, content)
temp = re.sub(pattern1 , ‘’, content)
print(temp)
print(f’There are {len(temp)} words ended with OS (other than OS and macOS) in the text.’)

Comment: I used the one above but I think it just print the last temp.. so I want to know how to do

Answer (score 1):

Use

```py
re.findall(r'\b(?:(?:Mac |mac)OS|OS X)\b', s)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/unpuIh/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      Mac                      'Mac '
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      mac                      'mac'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    OS                       'OS'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    OS X                     'OS X'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
```